# Как создать сервер с помощью домашнего пк?

Tags: python, сервер, веб-сервер

Помогите пожалуйста, нужно поднять сервер на простом домашнем компьютере. Как это сделать? В видео на YouTube ничего не понятно. Сервер будет использоваться для хранения, чтения и создания .txt файлов на нем.
Ход действий:

1. К серверу будет обращаться python'овский скрипт
2. При наличии файла с именем аккаунта будет открываться файл и проверяться файл на содержимое с паролем (внутри файла будет пароль)
3. Если файла с именем аккаунта нет, то создавать файл и записывать в него данные
4. Закрытие файла

Возможно ли это реализовать?

Comment: возможно. модуль socket вам поможет.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: А обращаться к нему откуда будут? Вероятно, проще всего поднять веб-сервис на `Flask`.

Comment: Обращаться будут с любой точки планеты. Пожалуйста, если есть возможность, можете предоставить код для сервера? Для клиента постараюсь додуматься сам.

Comment: @Cucumber78 Да там код простого веб-сервера в три строчки. А вот логику вам нужно самому будет придумывать. https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предоставлять конкретный код не буду, так как это не решит проблему вашего незнания, а также усугубит навык "Я не знаю как это делать, но и гуглить я не буду".

Для простого общения используйте библиотеку socket. В гугле [третья ссылка](https://iximiuz.com/ru/posts/writing-python-web-server-part-1/) после http серверов, которые вам не нужны, так как вам не нужен сайт.

Еще один [довольно полезный источник](https://habr.com/ru/post/149077/). Ну и [вот](https://pythonist.ru/rabota-s-setevymi-soketami-na-python/).

Пока этого будет достаточно, на мой взгляд. В свое время я на этой библиотеке писал мессенджер. Его логика была такая: Если подключается новый юзер, я отправляю всем тем, кто на данный момент подключен, определенную команду, содержащую аргументы времени и ника пользователя. По сути, сервер выполнял команду, получи от одного и отправь всем.

---

PS не забывайте, что гугл может ответить на 90% ваших вопросов.